# Fixed position header not sticking to the top of the page when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header that has a fixed position of top: 0 etc. Which works perfectly on desktop and laptop. But on mobile as you scroll and the top of the browser disappears there is a big white space above the header until the top of the browser fully disappears then it snaps to the top. I want it to always be pushed up to the top of the window. Anyone know how to avoid this?

heres where you can see what I mean;
http://79.170.40.172/allianceworkforce.co.uk/

```
#nav_bar{
    background-color: #404041;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Comment: What mobile platforms are you talking of?

Comment: Pretty common problem. Good article on the subject here: http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: I can't replicate the described issue on iOS 10.3.3

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am using an android mobile. Good to know thanks

Comment: Which Android version? On what browser (and version)? On which phone?